# resignFirstResponder and proofreader/PRDBinit 16 byte leak?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, uitextfield, uikeyboard

We're having a minor issue dealing with the pesky iPhone keyboard.

We have tried

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

     [oneTextField resignFirstResponder];  // 100% leak for 16 bytes 
     // some more textfields.

}
```

and tried using

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

    [oneTextField resignFirstResponder]; // 100% leak for 16 bytes 
     // some more textfields.

return YES;

}
```

And however we do this, we get a pesky leak of 16 bytes. This ONLY happens once. We get no more than 16 bytes of leaks during a 30minute run with the instruments throughout the entire application.

The leak occurs when the keyboard dissapeares after you've tapped all of the textfields and tapping either the background/returnkey.

Now i'm calling out for a helping hand, since this is the only remaining memory leak that we have in our current project, and we want it taken care of. And i'm speaking in mafia terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved by getting a new iPhone. For those of you that also has a leak such as this, one of my coworkers said that this is a 100% false-positive.

Happy coding!

Comment: Getting a new iPhone, are you serious?

Comment: "Getting a new iPhone" made my day - but wtf?